# PrestaSitemapBundle and multiple definition of class RouterInterface

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony

Trying to setup PrestaSitemapBundle, but when I try to add listener an error happens.

https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSitemapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/5-Usage-Event_Listener.md

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\EventListener\SitemapListener::__construct() must implement
>   interface Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface, array given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/websitename/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on
>   line 3268 and defined" at n/a in
>   /var/www/websitename/src/AppBundle/EventListener/SitemapListener.php
>   line 28

services.yml

```
services:
     sitemap.listener:
         class: AppBundle\EventListener\SitemapListener
         arguments:
            - ["@router"]
         tags: [{name: "presta.sitemap.listener"}]
```

Moreover PhpStorm shows that "multiple definition of class Routerinterface".

Is it connected with error somehow?

[image: PhpStorm notification]

Comment: Can you show the service definition for your listener?

Comment: You mean in service.yml?  Added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your service definition.

Both..

```
array:
    - 1
    - 2
```

..and..

```
array: [1, 2]
```

..are ways to define a named array.

Your service definition...

```
arguments:
    - ['@router']
```

.. is essentially creating an array with the first value being an array with '@router' as the first value of the internal array. To fix this you need to pick one of the ways to define your array. So either..

```
arguments:
    - '@router'
```

.. or ..

```
arguments: ['@router']
```